# Covariance in Autofac?

Tags: domain-driven-design, autofac

I am using AutoFAC 2.2.4 and have a question about covariance in container resolution.

I have a base interface definition for my repositories:

```
IRepository<T, TKey>
```

Which has Find(Tkey), FindAll(), etc.

It is used, for example, like this:

```
IRepository<Catalog, int>
```

meaning a Catalog has an integer key. I registered its repository like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<CatalogRepository>()
    .As<IRepository<Catalog, int>>();
```

All was well. 
Later on I realized I needed an additional type of .Find() so I defiend a new interface:

```
ICatalogRepository : IRepository<Catalog, int>
{
    Catalog Find(string name);
}
```

And I changed the registeration:

```
builder.RegisterType<CatalogRepository>()
    .As<ICatalogRepository>();
```

But now attempts to resolve IRepository < Catalog, int > fail. I thought Autofac would recognize the relationship to ICatalogRepository and resolve it. I have had to do this:

```
builder.RegisterType<CatalogRepository>()
    .As<ICatalogRepository>()
    .As<IRepository<Catalog, int>>();
```

To get them both to resolve. (There are still calls to resolve IRepository from other generic entity manipulation tools that are unaware of the derived interface.) Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. However, you can take a look at the [assembly scanning](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Scanning) feature and the AsImplementedInterfaces method in particular.